# Failed to authenticate with NimbusJwtDecoder withJwkSetUri

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am trying to setup Resource Server to validate jwt tokens with Authentication server by using NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri

Following is my configuration in Resource server

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     http.oauth2ResourceServer(c -> {
        c.jwt(j -> {
           j.decoder(jwtDecoder());
        });
     });
     http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
     RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
     List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = rest.getInterceptors();
     interceptors.add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor("client1","secret1"));
     interceptors.add(new LoggingInterceptor());
     rest.setInterceptors(interceptors);
     return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token_key").restOperations(rest).build();
  }

}
```

And I have simple endpoint in Resource server to test

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

  @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

However when I access "/hello" with access token already got from auth server then I get unauthorised response and observe following logs in Resource server.

```
Response body: {"alg":"SHA256withRSA","value":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAo8ieQxTVHq4jBSM3JpO7UcFOa5UrorX5KhRbMqEtT746yGTqqv+t1EW6l8G31bGc6G/IHy7032vpKNxAgLVcoCrdoOakbGLb1y2+ElB9QmEEEplARWLQ43t47ywd0UA7MhF9WIbud1Z6kqySrsrBTzjPu+fwCElzUFveyaiPsZDlrEAU6yMLQ23nEP3bBCgDtGMVs1a7RsmAzfUsruelqNaAQQamobkjEMWB8ewZWjtsriIldNjGEAUznw4bcJ963ExtmgfMAHS7XhuWqu58yIzdBopxhZvt/falc5cyp7OCP1ZPEjkHJ5TikJksqOgDgWhiIVtr/3cUjd8vnX4y4QIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"}
2021-05-15 11:54:47.468 DEBUG 40223 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2021-05-15 11:54:47.468 DEBUG 40223 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
2021-05-15 11:54:47.469 DEBUG 40223 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2021-05-15 11:54:47.469 DEBUG 40223 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

It seems auth server was able to provide public key successfully but resource server could not use this public key to validate provided jwt token.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you send Authorisation header to service?

Comment: Yes, I passed access token already got from auth server in Authorization header

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add class @EnableAuthorizationServer anotation but not working please read this Outh2 documentation https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html